# Replace Like in SQL for ENUM

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Currently I am having success with the following query:

```
if (isset($data->action_needed_status) && $data->action_needed_status != '') {
    $query->where('status', 'like', '%'.$data->action_needed_status.'%');
    $query_count->where('status', 'like', '%'.$data->action_needed_status.'%');
```

The complaint was this:

> Since status is an ENUM field you know that any valid status value
>   passed should match exactly. There shouldn't be a need for using LIKE
>   in the where statements.

What would be the best way to have same result without using LIKE?

Comment: Are you trying to match more than one status?

Comment: No just one status from a drop down select.

Comment: Use `=` instead of `like` and get rid of the `%`.

Comment: $query->where('status', '=' .$d ?  @Barmar

Comment: `$query->where('status', '=', $data->action_needed_status)`

Comment: Just like testing any other datatype for equality. There's nothing special about ENUM.

Comment: ORM usually have a more compact syntax for doing equality tests, since it's the usual comparison.